# Contract jurisdiction? - UK client purchasing from Spain

Tags: contract-law, jurisdiction

I'm a UK reg'd business looking to appoint a Spanish company to do some web development. Which legal jurisdiction would it be most normal and fair to have to contract written under? (small total service sum of ~£20k)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Contracts are not required to be fair

You would find it easier if it was under English law, they would find it easier under Spanish law so it's inherently unfair. Between you you have to decide which it will be and price the risk accordingly.

In general, courts will honour an 'election of jurisdiction clause'. However, there will be laws in both jurisdictions that cannot be excluded by contract.

Most commonly, the party drafting the contract will nominate their own jurisdiction.

Comment: Is there a normal form on such cross border contract jurisdictions? i.e. written under purchasers law, or perhaps where the bulk of the work is actually carried out?

Comment: @jbk usually the party drafting the contract will write in their jurisdiction

Comment: Thanks Dale, would you add yor last comment to the answer please and I'll mark the Q answered .